# Beginner level Java - Zellers algotrithm

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, counter

I have an assignment in Java (intro to programming) based on Zellers algorithm, Write input as integers, loop and counter code and I have to use a while loop to get the day and year first then the month, treating Jan & Feb as prior year. I thought I was at least in the ballpark, but cannot get my code to work. Any suggestions on how to improve?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class ZellersAlgorithm {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declarations go here

int count, Month, Day, Year;
int C = (int)(Year / 100.0); // the century 
int D = (int) (Year % 100); // The year of the century
int K = Day;
int M = Month;
int G = (K + (int)((26 * (M + 1)) / 10.0) + C + (int)(C / 4.0) 
        + (int)(D / 4.0) + (5 * D)) % 7;

Month = (M);
Day = (K);
Year = (C + D);


Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//Title
System.out.println("Project 2 - Zellers Algorithm");


while(M != 0){


    System.out.print("Enter a numberic day: ");
    K = scan.nextInt();
        if (K == 0) 
            System.out.print("Saturday");
        else if (K == 1)
            System.out.print("Sunday");
        else if (K == 2)
            System.out.print("Monday");
        else if (K == 3)
            System.out.print("Tuesday");
        else if (K == 4)
            System.out.print("Wednesday");
        else if (K == 5)
            System.out.print("Thursday");
        else
            System.out.print("Friday");

    System.out.print("Enter a nummeric year: ");
    ///Need to convert 4 digit year to C & D variable
    // Add counter, possibly include length counter 1st 2 digits are century/C last 2 are year
    Year = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a numeric month: ");
    M = scan.nextInt();

    switch (M) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("March");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("April");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("May");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("June");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("July");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("August");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("September");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("October");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("November");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("December");
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("January" + D + count--);
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("February" + D + count--);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid month.");
        break;

 }

}

//formula one
    //G =([2.6M-.2]+K+D+[D/4]+[C/4]-2C mod 7;
    //display as integer
String result = "Day of the week is ";
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify on what *but cannot get my code to work* means.

Some comments though

- `int count, Month, Day, Year;` -- variables should be lower case (this does not change the behaviour of your program but is common code style for Java programs - Most people would read `Year` as a class name). The same goes for "all uppercase" like `C`, which is normally used for constants
- Use variable names that express meaning. `M`, `K`, `C`, `D` do not help the reader to understand, what they mean.